# Modify Manifest file

Tags: java, apache, maven, war, pom.xml

I have an issue that after read two pages in google about it I can still not found the solution.
I want just create a manifest file into my war file and introduce the version of my application. I´m using mave-war-plugin of apache.
Using version 2.0.2 I achieve to create the manifest file, but just with the default information:

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Built-By: ***********
  Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
  Created-By: Apache Maven 3.1.1
  Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

The code of 2.0.2 is this one:

```
                  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>2.1.0</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But like I said, I cannot introduce the new attribute "Implementation-Version"

And if I try to use the last version of the plugin I cannot create the manifest file at all.

```
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>2.1.0</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I´m using Maven 3 and I dont have create any MANIFEST.FM file in META-INF.

I try to create my own MANIFEST.FM in my META-INF. with this template, to see if would be possible to just set the values but nothing as well. Like I said I try everything!

```
 Specification-Title: ****
 Specification-Vendor: Company Name
 Implementation-Title: Portal web
 Implementation-Version: ${Implementation-Version}
 Implementation-Vendor:*****
 Build-Jdk: ${jdk.version}
```

After continue investigating, I see that my war file has 2 overlays. So after read about it I add into the main overlay, the plugin with the modification of the Manifest.

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And in the child wars the plugin like.

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
```

But then the manifest is created with the default values, and the maven folder with the pom.properties, but in the child wars nothing is created in the META-INF

Regards.

Comment: you just want to edit MENIFEST? like we edit text file

Comment: I want to create the MANIFEST with this attribute "Implementation-Version".

Comment: Implementation-Version should be added for you because you specified `addDefaultImplementationEntries` and set it to true.  Try actually specifying the latest version of the plugin (2.4) to see if that helps.  Also, look to see if there are parent or child POMs that may be changing the archive configuration when merged with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but If you read the post I try with the last version as well. And using that one, the manifest file is not even created.